# Alphas vs. portfolio rank w.r.t. factors in Fama-French 3-factor model

Tags: asset-pricing, factor-models, fama-french

In the Fama-French 3-factor model, is there a point in looking at the relationship between the estimated alphas for the 25 test portfolios and the size-rank or value-rank of these portfolios?
<del>Also, might it be true that there will be no linear relationship between the alphas and the size-rank (or value-rank) by design?</del>

I have done the looking, both in 2D (alphas vs. size-rank, alphas vs. value-rank) and 3D (alphas vs. size-rank vs. value-rank) plots, but nothing jumped out at me. But then again, I was not sure what I should look for.